# Formatting to differentiate text/number from formulae

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, excel-2013

I have to change the format of certain cells based on their content and for this I was thinking of using the rules of "conditional formatting". I would like a format if the content is a simple text/number (user input) and another format if it is a formula.

How can I format cells depending on the type of content?

Comment: What have you already tried?  How did that fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest one rule for each format, say Formula:

```
=ISFORMULA(A1)
```

and:

```
=A1<>""
```

but make sure the upper one here is the upper one in the rule set and check "Stop If True".

[image: SO26364812 example]